# How to add Key on existing array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

im currently working on a project that uses javascript as it's front end and im having a bit trouble on adding a key on my existing array.

i have an object that i wanted to be converted on array javascript.

here is my code on how to convert my object to array.

```
        var obj = data[0];
        var site_value = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });

        var site_key = $.map( obj, function( value, key ) {
          return key;
        });
```

the site_value has the value of my objects.
the site_key has the key.

i want to add my site_key to the site_value array as a Key.

example data:

site_value:
    0:Array[4]
      0:Array[4]
      1:Array[1]
      2:Array[1]
      3:Array[0]

site_key:

```
Array[49]
  0:"AGB"
  1:"BAK"
  2:"BAN"
  3:"BAR"
```

i want my array to be

```
AGB:Array[4]
  0:Array[4]
  1:Array[1]
  2:Array[1]
  3:Array[0]
```

Update:

Here is my object.

```
Array[1]0: 
  Object
    AGB: Array[4]
    BAK: Array[4]
    BAN: Array[4]
```

etc.

Comment: how does your obj looks like?

Comment: i updated the question thanks

Comment: it looks like you are trying to get multidimensional array like php style but javascript use objects for this.

Comment: Why you mix `key` and `index` in your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost done it and I have modified it a bit below to return it as array object,

```
var obj = data[0];

var site_value = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { 
    var output = {};
    output[key] = obj[key];

    return output;
});
```

Comment: is that an 0 or an O ?

Comment: Sorry, that's a variable. Renamed it as `output`.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but yes it returns an array but inside of it is an object and inside of it is an array again. i want it to be an array with an array with the ex. Agb[4]

Comment: Can you place the data for your input and the output you want exactly?The one you provided above is a bit unclear. You have mentioned just one with a key `AGB` and other with numbers

Comment: Create a fiddle by replacing `data[0]` in `var obj = data[0];` with actual data.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, sorry if I am.  I think you would like to use a key "AGB" instead of an integer for an array index.  In this case, you would probably be better served to use an object instead of an array. Maybe something like this

```
var myObject = {
 AGB: Array[4],
 AGBarrays: [Array[4],Array[1],Array[1],Array[0]]
};
```

Then you could access AGB by key and your additional arrays by index

Comment: I need it to be an array because the data will be loaded on the highchart.js

Comment: is this because highcharts gives it the description of the index?

Comment: if this is the case, use a series

Comment: series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]